# How can I check the source of all image tags in user input using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, contenteditable

I have a form for user input in which users can add images hosted elsewhere using a form. The images are displayed as a small icon which is both a link and which will load an image into a div with stacking order +1 on hover. The image source address is stored in the link tag only.

I am using a `<div />` with `contenteditable=true` for the user input. The icon is appended when the form is used. The code for this part works fine. What I would like to do is check the source of all image tags to make sure that users are not adding their own html to display full size images in their post.

I am using php on the backend to remove all tags except links and images, but would like to use jQuery to check the src of the image tags before posting.

```
<a href="image_source.jpg"><img src="my_icon" /></a> //this is what my form will input

<img src="anything_else"> //this is what I want to prevent
```

Update: I apologize if this is not clear. Essentially, I don't want the user to be able to input any html of their own. If they want to add an image, they have to use my built in form which inserts something like above.

Comment: **too much text** . visualize it with simple example.

Comment: It's not a very secure solution, since any savvy user will be able to circumvent the jQuery-script.

Comment: I still don't understand the question.  Can you give an example of good input and bad input?

Answer (score 1):

Especially for your site following code alerts the links for all images:

```
$('.postimage').each(function(){
   alert($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Comment: Interestingly, it won't even recognize user input img tags

Comment: I've tried both. Your first example was closer. It didn't recognize the user input tags but it recognized the tags put in by the form. My guess is that this has something to do with the contenteditable div. Any more ideas?

Comment: I have your code in place. My form inputs images with src='/images/imagelink.jpg'. Check it out at http://67.174.10.236/community-garden/seed-planter.php

Comment: The problem is if the user tries to put in html directly rather than use my form. Try to code in an image tag and you will see. I have put your first code back in.

Comment: First of all javascript is a client-side scripting language, everybody can manipulate the html and js code, you can't prevent it. You can only try to make it more user-friednly. Only on backend-side checks can be secure.  If you want to prevent accepting tags after click on `Insert Image` button, add a url-check in the `insertSeedImage` function. E.g.: `if (url.indexOf('<') >= 0) { return; }`

Comment: Thank you for your time and patience. I am not worried about tags inserted by the Insert Image button. That button inserts a small icon, which is what I want. I just don't want users who know simple html to directly code image tags into the form (the large contenteditable div).

Answer (score 1):

You could loop over the images and then check the src attribute.

```
$("img").each(function(index) {
    if ($(this).attr("src") == ...) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

See http://api.jquery.com/each/ and http://api.jquery.com/attr/ for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Say we have the `<div id="editor" />` the jQuery script would look something like this:

```
var srcs = [];
jQuery ('div#editor img').each (function () {
  srcs.push (jQuery (this).attr ('src'));
});
```

`srcs` will now hold all the `src`-attributes from the `<img />`-tags provided in the `<div id="editor" />` tag.

Answer (score 1):

I have an answer. When users input a `<` or `>` in a contenteditable="true" div, the browser replaces them with the html notation `&lt;` and `&gt;`. The good news is the images would have never displayed when outputting the user comment. The bad news is that the jQuery based solutions given above will not work to remove the ugly coding. I ended up using php to do it with

```
$post = $_POST['comment'];
$imgcheck = true;
$stringstart = 0;

while($imgcheck == 'true'){
    if($stringstart = strpos($post,'&lt;img',$stringstart)){
        if ($stringend = strpos($post,'&gt;',$stringstart)){
            $strlength = $stringend - $stringstart +4;
            $substring = substr($post,$stringstart,$strlength);
            if (!preg_match('~src="\/images\/ImageLink.jpg"~',$substring)){
                $post = str_replace($substring, "", $post);
            }
            else{
                $stringstart = $stringend;
            }

        }
        else{
            $imgcheck = 'false';
        }
    }
    else{
            $imgcheck = 'false';
    }

}
```